# Java Apache HTTPClient do not encode POST entity

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

I have an endpoint that requires an 'authenticity_token' that is in the format like:

```
Iq2rNXN+OxERv+s6TSloJfKkPZVvqnWe1m0NfODB5OI=
```

However, sometimes it has "special" characters, such as:

```
E7IzeP73OgPGgXM&#47;up295ky1mMQMio2Nb8HMLxJFyfw=
```

This gets encoded to:

```
E7IzeP73OgPGgXM%26%2347%3Bup295ky1mMQMio2Nb8HMLxJFyfw%3D
```

For some reason, the endpoint does not like the encoding of those special characters and will think the token is invalid. Is it possible to add a POST variable that does not encode specific values? I am currently doing something like:

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL + NEW_FINDING);
    List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("foo", foo));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("authenticity_token", authenticityToken));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `ByteArrayEntity` or `StringEntity` instead of `UrlEncodedFormEntity` and do the encoding yourself. It should look something like `foo=var1&bar=var2`. 
You have to set `Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
You may want to find out what your endpoint expects as a charset parameter for the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` value of the Content-Type header. Then pass it as a parameter to the `UrlEncodedFormEntity` constructor. This should be the right fix.

Comment: The problem is that id like to use the UrlEncodedFormEntity for the rest of the parameters, I just need to be able to have the authenticity_token not encoded...

Comment: Just use the first option then: ByteArrayEntity or StringEntity with Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded. UrlEncodedFormEntity does exactly this but it encodes the parameters for you.