# Disable URLEncoding on HTTP Post request with commons HTTPClient

Tags: java, post, httpclient, urlencode

I am desperately trying to tell the commons HTTP Client not to urlencode my payload (XML) on a POST request. Is there any way to do this? If you can recommend any other class that does not urlencode by default I would be happy to try it.

Thanks in advance for every input.

BR
Stefan

Comment: Please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116219/html-prevent-url-encoding-of-post-form) is what you are after

Comment: Hi Rao, sadly it does not. Content-Type: text/plain does not prevent the apache HTTPClient from using urlencode.

Comment: Stefan, please, read the TAGs you used. The `DO NOT USE` is not rethorical. Please, change the tag to the httpClient you are using. Since they are not equal, its likely this is an issue, also, we cant help if we have to guess parts of the system or the question. If its the Java Apache Client, [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885780/java-apache-httpclient-do-not-encode-post-entity)